# Why my image update is not "binded"?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm

I have a gird view of my objects "Sessions". On user selection, every Session's Image gets display in an Image on my GUI. I have this routine where, on user `SelectedSession`, it *Deletes any existing image*, *Takes a new Image* `frameSource`, *Saves it* locally and then *sets the private member variable* `ImagePath` as its path:

```
    public Session SelectedSession { get { return selectedSession; } set { SetValue(ref selectedSession, value); } }
    public BitmapSource SessionImage { get { return sessionImage; } private set { SetValue(ref sessionImage, value); } }

//..
    public void TakeSessionImage(BitmapSource frameSource)
    {
        if (SelectedSession != null)
        {
            if (File.Exists(SelectedSession.ImagePath)) 
                File.Delete(SelectedSession.ImagePath); // delete old - works

            SelectedSession.ImagePath = FileStructure.CurrentSessionPath + "\\" + SelectedSession.Name + ".png"; // set ImagePath - works - Technically it does not change. I kept it if I needed later to add anything to the file name like GUID or whatever
            ImageIO.RotateAndSaveImage(SelectedSession.ImagePath, (WriteableBitmap)frameSource, -270); // save new image - works
            SessionImage = SelectedSession.LoadImageFromFile(); // binded the image to display
        }
    }
```

Binding in Xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="currentSessionImage" Source="{Binding SessionImage}"/>
```

In "Session.cs" class:

```
public BitmapImage LoadImageFromFile()
{
    if (File.Exists(ImagePath)) // image path is correct
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = new Uri(ImagePath);
            image.EndInit();
            return image;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This has been debugged and all statements are valid. `SessionImage`is my property that is "binded" to an Image on my GUI. However, a very weird behavior is happening:

- It is deleting the old image file and I can see that in windows explorer that the file is gone.
- It is saving the new one correctly
- It is loading the new image from the correct path
- But then, it only displays the very First Image I ever took.

Whatever new image I send. It always displays the same image I took the first time. Could anyone please check it for me? I validated the whole code and all values are logical. No syntax errors anywhere.

**Edit:**

```
protected virtual bool SetValue<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
    {
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

//..

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    try
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `SessionImage`?

Comment: Ow sorry I missed its property. One sec. Thanks @entropic

Comment: Does it work correctly if you use `image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;` so there is no image caching at all? Based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption(v=vs.110).aspx), it looks like `OnLoad` means it will cache the image OnLoad, and reuse the cached value.

Comment: What's the code for SetValue?

Comment: @PeterI `SetValue` is a template for both `SessionImage` and `SelectedSession` and any other property. I will add it. See edited please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF caches bitmaps that are loaded from URIs. To avoid that, load the BitmapImage directly from file instead:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(ImagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    image.StreamSource = fileStream;
    image.EndInit();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks. Worked ))